# Is it possible for a premise to be both tautologous and contradictory?

Tags: logic, premises

Is it possible for a premise to be both tautologous and contradictory? If it is possible, how so?

Answer (score 6):

**NO**: A premise is a logical *sentence*.  It can be *atomic*, (*e.g.* **A**) or *complex* (*e.g.* **¬A → B**).

But no sentence can be at the same time a *tautology*, *i.e.* true for every interpretation, and *contradictory*, *i.e.* false for every interpretation.